# How should I calculate the average speed by road segment for multiple segments?

Tags: sql, sql-server, mean

I have a table of driver speeds and road segments:

```
driver_lpr    |   segment    |    speed
  0000001     |       A      |     30
  0000002     |       B      |     60
  0000003     |       A      |     50
  0000004     |       A      |     100
  0000005     |       B      |     60
```

And I want to have a table of average speed per segment

```
segment   |   average speed
   A      |         47.368
   B      |         60
```

How can this be done in SQL ?

Comment: Under meta discussion [How can I demonstrate to voters that a question is less trivial than it seems?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/314789)

Comment: It probably would have helped if the OP had mentioned that the 'average' he expects is not 'your everyday average'. TBH, I had never even heard of the term `Harmonic mean` and it took me a while to realise his example result was 'strange' =)

Comment: He *may* not have known, @deroby (Alejandro, can you clarify?) - wouldn't be the first time someone's used arithmetic mean for averaging rates and gotten incorrect results without realizing why.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

When averaging speeds, the [harmonic mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_mean) is in need.

The straight forward `AVG()` approach is wrong, the arithmetic mean yields the wrong result for average velocity.

There is no predefined function for the harmonic mean, but it could be achieved with this query:

```
SELECT segment,
       COUNT(*)/SUM(1e0/speed) AS avg_speed
FROM T 
GROUP BY segment
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9986d/3)

Comment: This is true if the segments are the same distance, if the time interval is the same then a standard arithmetic mean suffices, if neither then a weighted harmonic or arithmetic mean is required.

Answer (score 3):

This is little bit complex, but will take care of `0` speed also. I have 2 similar queries to do it based on different scenarios.

Assume your source table like below.

```
+-------------+----------+-------+
| driver_lpr  | segment  | speed |
+-------------+----------+-------+
|    0000001  | A        |    30 |
|    0000002  | B        |    60 |
|    0000003  | A        |    50 |
|    0000004  | A        |   100 |
|    0000005  | B        |    60 |
|    0000006  | B        |     0 |
|    0000007  | C        |     0 |
+-------------+----------+-------+
```

I have added 2 new rows with `0` speed.

**Case 1:**

- Addition of a `0` speed in segment `B`, will give average speed as
  `40` `(60*2+0*1)/(2+1)`.
- Addition of a new segment, `C` with `0`
  speed will give average speed as `0`

So output would be

```
+----------+-------------------+
| segment  |   average_speed   |
+----------+-------------------+
| A        | 47.36842105263158 |
| B        | 40                |
| C        | 0                 |
+----------+-------------------+
```

**<kbd>**[`SQLFiddle Demo CASE 1`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/070e5/2)**</kbd>**

Case 2:

- There will be no change in average speed of `B` with addition of a
  `0`.
- However, a new segment `C` will have `0` average speed.

Output would be

```
+----------+-------------------+
| segment  |   average_speed   |
+----------+-------------------+
| A        | 47.36842105263158 |
| B        | 60                |
| C        | 0                 |
+----------+-------------------+
```

**<kbd>**[`SQLFiddle Demo CASE 2`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/070e5/5)**</kbd>**

Query for Case 1:

```
with tbl1 as
    (SELECT segment,
    case when speed = 0 then cast(0 as float) else 
    cast(1 as float)/cast(speed as float)
    end as newspeed
    FROM T 
    ),
tbl2 as
    (
        select segment,cast(1 as float)/avg(newspeed) as avgspeed,count(*) as cnt 
        from tbl1
        where newspeed <> 0
        group by segment
    union
        select segment,0 as avgspeed,count(*) as cnt
        from tbl1
        where newspeed =0
        group by segment
    )
select segment,
    sum(avgspeed*cnt)/sum(cnt) as "average_speed" 
from tbl2
group by segment
```

Query for Case2

```
with tbl1 as
    (SELECT segment,
    case when speed = 0 then cast(0 as float) else 
    cast(1 as float)/cast(speed as float)
    end as newspeed
    FROM T 
    ),
tbl2 as
    (
        select segment,cast(1 as float)/avg(newspeed) as avgspeed,count(*) as cnt 
        from tbl1
        where newspeed <> 0
        group by segment
    union
        select segment,0 as avgspeed,count(*) as cnt
        from tbl1
        where newspeed =0
        group by segment
    )
select segment,
    sum(avgspeed) as "average_speed" 
from tbl2
group by segment
```

Comment: How can there be a speed of 0? That would mean they are stationary and therefore could not complete any road segments.

Comment: Just wanted to cover all possible scenarios.