# Calculate average speed over x-distance

Tags: math, game-engine, distance

This is probably a very easy calculation to do, but I cant seem to solve it.
Lets say we have the following data to work with:

- **distance from A to B** = 1243 meters
- **default speed to move an object from A to B** = 2030 meters per second

The first 118 meters are at a speed of **1450** meters per second. 
After those 118 meters its back to its default value of **2030**.

How do I calculate the average speed over a distance of **1243** meters?

Comment: Rate * time = distance. Derive from there.

Comment: I'd be curious what process could change the speed of an object from 1450 to 2030 meter per second after it has travelled a distance of 118 meters already.

Comment: This is a programming site, not a maths site. Try http://math.stackexchange.com/ instead.

Comment: @Enigmativity you are totally right, my apologies.

Comment: The answer is `1955.73554487676 m/s`, btw. That might help you to confirm when you figure out how to do it.

Comment: @gnasher729 magic and videogames :)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about [math.se] instead of programming or software development.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34794664/how-should-i-calculate-the-average-speed-by-road-segment-for-multiple-segments/34795821#34795821

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dist = vel * time`, or for time `time = dist/vel`. You have two segments of the journey you are concerned about, the first `118` meters and the rest `1243 - 118`. Once you find the time for each segment, you can find the total time:

```
time for first 118 + time for rest = total time;
```

Once you have the total time, the average velocity over the total distance is simply:

```
vavg = total dist/ total time;
```

or in your case

```
vavg = 1243 / ((118/1450) + ((1243-118)/2030));

     = 1243 / (.08 + .55);

     = 1973 m/s.
```

Comment: Yes, the numbers were simply approximations, (2 decimal points). The example was about the *"how"* part. You are 100% correct that the calculation will be highly sensitive to the number of significant digits.

Answer (score 0):

Average speed is the total distance traveled divided by the time elapsed. In other words,

V = dx /dt

If we start at x = 0, then x1 is 0,  so we have dx = x2 - x1 = 1234m - 0m = 1234m.
We also have to calculate time for the following reason: the acceleration is instant, so we have two intervals of speed and distance to consider. So the time elapsed, dt, is equal to the time the journey on the first interval took plus the time of the journey on the second interval.

Solving:

t1 = dist / speed = 118m / 1450 m/s = 0.081s

t2 = dist / speed = (1234m - 118m) / 2030 m/s = 0.55s

Which means the total time elapsed is 0.63s.

Leaving us with an a speed of dx / dt = 1234m / (t1 + t2) = 1234m / 0.63s = 1,958.73 m/s.